# Easy UI Grid alignment is not working In all resolutions With A Static Table

Tags: html, css, jquery-easyui

[image]
In my table the `status` table header and select dropdown should align in any resolution. In 1024 resolution it's fine but in other resolutions it's not.
Please give me a suggestion how to solve in any resolution and in all browsers except Safari.
This Is Easy UI Plug In

Comment: in my System in 1920 Resolution select drop down not aligned with header name1 . it forewords left of 7px

Comment: how can i fixed it ? Is there any Browser specific issues .

Comment: Works for me with width of 1920px as well. Can you provide a screenshot of the error you see?

Comment: This Is Easy UI Grid Plug in Sorry For My Wrong  Explanation

Comment: Please Give Me A Suggestion

Comment: If you mean the dropdown should be exactly above the "Status" column, that isn't very clear. You should have said so. Also, why did you remove the HTML source from your question? That should still be there too.

Comment: Ya Right Drop down Should be Exactly Above On Status Column At Any Resolution And Any Browser .